# How to solve andriod build problem?

Tags: unity, android

I downloaded Unity 2021.3.6f1 from Unity Hub for Windows and Android Build but Unity didn't download the gradle which is required for Android build so i download gradle 7.5 and linked it to unity but when i try to build andriod build it show same error as before(as without gradle) .
Error:

> FileNotFoundException: Failed to find $C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.6f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\GradleTemplates\mainTemplate.gradle
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.GetTemplate (System.String toolsPath, System.String fileName) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor+d__21.MoveNext () (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
> UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.SetupBeeDriver (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
> UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
> Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
> UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
> UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <0bc7e9c04c1540528b26863a0cb726ae>:0)
> UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 50 seconds (49803 ms)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <44a70d1b13cf47e29810e30f45ffae08>:0

What is the solution?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your linking is done correctly? The file Not Found error is switching between / and \ in the path

Comment: [Is this existing Q&A of any use to you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72920555/3064164)?